# How can I know the length of each part of the arrow and what their full length?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, geometry

How can I know the length of each part of the arrow and what their full length?

```
points = {{6, 32}, {9, 53}, {18, 42}, {32, 51}};
Graphics[{Arrow[points]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can know the length of each part of the arrow and his full length in this way:

```
distList = 
 EuclideanDistance[points[[# + 1]], points[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[points] - 1] // N
Plus @@ distList
```

> {21.2132,14.2127,16.6433}
>
> 52.0692

Comment: Same idea but more concise: `EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[points, 2, 1]`

Comment: ...and then use `Total[]` afterwards.

Answer (score 8):

To be concise in a different way:

```
N@Total@(Norm /@ Differences@points)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
N[ArcLength/@Line/@Partition[points,2,1]]
```

> {21.2132, 14.2127, 16.6433}

```
N@ArcLength[Line[points]]
```

> 52.0692