# How could I do all of this in a more effective way?

Tags: list-manipulation

Let us suppose that the points below define a path:

```
p = {{0, 0}, {5, 8.07774721}, {10, 4.24499363}, {20, 9.28880172}};
Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[p]}]
```

[image]

With the function from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128023/29734) I get the distances between points. They are not integer values and do not need to be integers.

```
partialPath = 
 EuclideanDistance[p[[# + 1]], p[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[p] - 1] // N
```

> $\{9.5,6.3,11.2\}$

With the function below I have given all the way:

```
pathTotal = Plus @@ partialPath
```

> $27$

I am wanting to subdivide all the path into 300 equal parts.

```
pathTotal/300
```

> $0.09$

The function below describes the percentage of each part of the path with respect to the total path:
$9.5/27 = 0.351852$
$6.3/27 = 0.233333$
$11.2/27 = 0.414815$

```
porcentPath = {#/pathTotal} & /@ partialPath
Plus @@ porcentPath
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0.351852 \\
>  0.233333 \\
>  0.414815 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$
>
> ${1.}$

I intended to use these percentages to try to obtain the value of $0.9$ obtained with `pathTotal/300`.
$105.556$ divisions for Step1
$70$ divisions for Step2
$124.444$ divisions for Step3

```
subDivisions = porcentPath*300
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  105.556 \\
>  70. \\
>  124.444 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

With that done the difference between each point and tried to use the function `Subdivide` to try to get the points I want to:

```
d = Differences[p];
Subdivide[d[[#]], First@subDivisions[[#]]] & /@ Range[3]
```

But I get error

Then I round the values and I get sucess:

```
subDivisions2 = Round[subDivisions]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  106 \\
>  70 \\
>  124 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
d = Differences[p];
Subdivide[d[[#]], First@subDivisions2[[#]]] & /@ Range[3];
```

How could I do all of this in a more effective way?

Comment: I think [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21993) is a dupe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative approach using `LineScaledCoordinate` from `GraphUtilities`:

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]

p = {{0, 0}, {5, 8.07774721}, {10, 4.24499363}, {20, 9.28880172}};
n = 30;
pts = LineScaledCoordinate[p, N@(#/n)] & /@ Range[0, n];

ListPlot[{p, pts}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red]}, 
 Joined -> {True, False}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:**

Even simpler alternative is to use `MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}`:

```
ListPlot[p, Joined -> True, MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, 
 Mesh -> (n-1), MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Medium]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This answer is closer than I intend to use. Mainly in exchange of directions, where I can see the constant length of 0.9 that I wanted.

Comment: I find more informations: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72427/linescaledcoordinate-problem-for-exact-coordinates

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this, except with the number of points you actually wanted:

```
p = {{0, 0}, {5, 8.07774721}, {10, 4.24499363}, {20, 9.28880172}};

n = 30;
partialPath = 
  EuclideanDistance[p[[# + 1]], p[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[p] - 1] // N;
nparts = n*partialPath/Total[partialPath] // Round;
check = TrueQ[n == Total@nparts]

s1 = Table[
   Subdivide[p[[i, 1]], p[[i + 1, 1]], nparts[[i]]], {i, 1, 
    Length[p] - 1}];
s2 = Table[
   Subdivide[p[[i, 2]], p[[i + 1, 2]], nparts[[i]]], {i, 1, 
    Length[p] - 1}];
s = Transpose[{Flatten@s1, Flatten@s2}];

Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[s],
  Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[p]}]
```

The list `s` will contain some redundant points.  One way to remove the redundancy is to use `s = Union[s]`.  A side effect of `Union`, however, is that it returns a sorted list.  The redundant points are given by `p[[2;;-2]]` so they could be removed using `DeleteCases`.